# Hive on tez,when set hive.tez.container.size=2048,query failed with Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

Tags: hive

Can not set hive.tez.container.size twice than mapreduce.map.memory.mb.Following is the detail error message:

```
***Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
]], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Container container_1449486079177_5311_01_000061 finished with diagnostics set to [Container failed, exitCode=1. Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1449486079177_5311_01_000061
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:702)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.launchContainer(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Shell output: main : command provided 1
main : user is nobody
main : requested yarn user is hadoop***
```

Comment: Did you check the YARN logs of that container #61? And also the YARN logs of the AppMaster (container #1)?

Comment: When I use the command ' yarn logs -applicationId application_1449486079177_5311_01_000061' to check the Yarn logs,I got the error tips:'Container: container_1449486079177_5311_01_000098 on *_8041
============================================================================================
LogType: stderr
LogLength: 50
Log Contents:
Error: Could not find or load main class Xmx1700m

LogType: stdout
LogLength: 0
Log Contents:',I know it cause I had set the running 'hive.tez.java.opts',not  'hive.tez.container.size'.Thank you very much.

Comment: Then you can mark my comment as "useful comment"  :-)